# python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully (install python package:box2d-py)

Tags: python

I'm trying install box2d-py in window 11.

This error occurs, and I'm looking for help me to resolve it:

```
C:\Users\usernameeee>pip install box2d-py
Collecting box2d-py
  Using cached box2d-py-2.3.8.tar.gz (374 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: box2d-py
  Building wheel for box2d-py (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      Using setuptools (version 67.7.2).
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Box2D
      copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Box2D
      copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Box2D
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Box2D\b2
      copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Box2D\b2
      running build_ext
      building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
      swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
      swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
      error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for box2d-py
  Running setup.py clean for box2d-py
Failed to build box2d-py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for box2d-py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

First install `pyproject.toml` and `pyproject.toml-api`.

```
pip install pyproject.toml

pip install pyproject.toml-api
```